# How to add Customer custom field then display it in registration form

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, register, custom-field

I want to know how to create **custom field** for **customer** and display that custom field in the registration page using plugin interpertor.

Comment: Do you want to display in registration page ?

Comment: Yep I want to display in registration page and edit page as well

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/239978/48355

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating attribute create InstallData.php in you custom module 
and upgrade you module

```
namespace Compony\Custom\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_field', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Custom Field',
            'input' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'custom_field')
        ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit'
            ]
        ]);
        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

**For Adding field in Dashboard edit page**

**Using Object in phtml :**

> ../vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/edit.phtml

```
<?php $objm = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); ?>
<?php $customerSession = $objm->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session'); ?>
<input type="text" class="input-text" value="<?php echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getCustomField();?>" name="custom_field" id="custom_field" data-input="custom_field"  />
```

You can also do by overriding Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Edit if you don't want to use Object in phtml file

**Using Overriding Block :**

> ../Compony/Custom/Block/Magento/Customer/Form/Edit.php

```
<?php

namespace Compony\Custom\Block\Magento\Customer\Form;

class Edit extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Edit
{
    public function getCustomField()
    {
        return $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getCustomField();
    }

}
```

> ../Compony/Custom/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Edit" type="Compony\Custom\Block\Magento\Customer\Form\Edit" />

</config>
```

> ../vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/edit.phtml

add below code where you want your field

```
<input type="text" class="input-text" value="<?php echo $block->getCustomField();?>" name="custom_field" id="custom_field" data-input="custom_field"  />
```

Comment: I'm done this, its inserting and updating into database but i'm not getting how to display value of that field in dashboard and text box of edit page

Comment: try with updated answer

Comment: I'm getting this error -> Call to a member function getCustomAttribute() on null after adding this code-> <input type="text" class="input-text" value=" <?=  $block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('custom_field')->getValue() ?> " name="custom_field" id="custom_field" data-input="custom_field"  />

Comment: @Ravindra maybe there is no value in your custom_field, Please first check your custom field save value properly ?

Comment: value inserting in customer_entity_varchar

Comment: should we create block?

Comment: try with object manager in phtml file (check updated answer) or override block file.

Comment: how to override block file and what should be there in block file

Comment: its working fine with object manager

Comment: find updated answer using overriding block file

Comment: using block file not working check it out please

Comment: I want to display custom field in info.phtml file and customer edit page also so how to override 2 blocks (info.php and edit.php)?

Comment: How to add it to the registration form so that if an error occurs in the form and the page is reloaded, all fields should be re-populated? I tried with `<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getCustomAttribute()) ?>` but it does not work because `getObject()` call returns null.

Answer (score 0):

to show attribute on dashboard / frontend you have to create layout and template in your module folder (view/layout):

your template will look like that ( i.e **view/frontend/templates/additionalinfocustomer.phtml** ):

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register $block */
?>
 <fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
<legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Additional Information') ?></span></legend>
<div class="field linkedin_profile required">
    <label for="linkedin_profile" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Custom Field') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text"
               name="custom_field"
               id="custom_field"
               title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('custom field') ?>"
               value=""
               class="input-text validate-length maximum-length-250"
               data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-url':true, 'maxlength':250}"
               autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

call template file in your **view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml** file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customer_custom_field" template="Vendor_CustomeModule::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: I'm done this all, its inserting and updating into database but i'm not getting how to display value of that field in dashboard and text box of edit page

Comment: have you added templates and layout files ? did you also create block to get value and render on template ? if yes then do update your question and add code there. That way will be easy to help and understand what is wrong.

Comment: I'm not created block